Reported speech changes the meaning?
Direct speech: "He did it when she arrived"
Reported speech: Tom said Joe had done it when she arrived
My question is: Isn't it that when we report the sentence it changes its meaning? In the original statement doing happens after her arrival and in reported speech it happes before. Am I right? If so how to avoid that change of meaning?

Are "He did when she arrived" the exact words spoken by someone called Tom?

Note that the 'direct speech' does not make any sense.

"He did when she arrived" requires a very unusual context to make sense. In an ongoing conversation, someone has just asserted that "he" didn't do something (contextually identified) before she arrived, and "He did [do it] when she arrived" requires stress on did when someone else counters that assertion.

But even with that contrived context, He did when she arrived implies he started doing it after she arrived, but Tom said he had done it when she arrived implies that he had already finished doing it by the time she arrived. To maintain temporal consistency, Tom said he did it when she arrived (or ...after she arrived).

@FumbleFingers - but the point I made in my first comment remains. If the direct speech is accurate, who is 'he'? It can't be 'Tom', surely?

@MichaelHarvey: True, but speculation on the intended meaning is pointless. If the OP can't or won't give a more meaningful context, so we know what's actually being spoken about, it should be closed on the grounds it "Needs details or clarity". user203412 - that means if you don't explain exactly what "He did when she arrived" is supposed to mean, the question will probably be closed rather than answered.

@ishtar I think OP meant we have to use an action verb in place of "did". Eg. "He cooked when she arrived.'

I have improved my mistakes

@user203412 Your basic assumption is incorrect. In the original statement doing happens after her arrival and in reported speech it happes before.  ""when"  doesn't imply whether it is before or after. "He did it when she arrived" You have to use before or after in place of "when" or use past perfect tense for the earlier action.

You do know Joe is usually a male name? So why 'she arrived'?

This question is similar to: Backshifting in reported speech - "I wanted to let you know that he HAS/HAD sent you the letter". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question has some possible typing errors that make it hard to know exactly what the given example is saying. But the main question is clear and reasonable:

When we report a sentence containing direct speech, does it change its meaning?
(And by implication, how can we avoid that?)

The short answer is, it may well do, so we need to be aware of that issue. However there are various ways to handle it. There are so many different cases that the following is just a starting example to illustrate the principle.
The (slightly edited) sentence from the OP is:

Tom said, "He did it when she arrived." (direct speech)

When converted to indirect speech it might read:

Tom said he had done it when she arrived. (indirect speech)

And now we have a problem with the pronoun. He in the direct speech is clearly someone other than Tom. But in the indirect speech the sentence by itself leads us to think Tom did it. So we would have to make enough of a change to retain the same essential meaning:

Tom said that Joe had done it when she arrived. (I'm imagining a context here that lets us know who the other guy is.)
Tom said that the other person had done it when she arrived. (If we don't have a name.)

The point here is that reported speech changes the style of the writing but ideally it won't change the content of the story. It's okay to alter the way the story is reported in order to communicate the essential meaning.
Regarding the tenses, we have the same potential problem:

Tom said, "He did it when she arrived." (This implies the doing and arriving happened at the same time.)
Tom said that Joe had done it when she arrived. (This is ambiguous. The doing now could be before or at the same time as the arriving.)

So if it's important to keep the same timing as the direct speech, I would simply say:

Tom said that Joe did it when she arrived.

I suspect the perfect tense is used here because of the (wrong) idea that the tenses have to be back shifted. The perfect tense can be used, but if it risks changing the intended meaning, just use another tense. No tense has to be applied religiously, and the simple past/present/future pattern is often good enough.

I understand that we don"t have to back shift yet let's assume there's no other context and you here this sentence "Tom said that Joe had done it when she arrived." What are your thoughts? Do you think he did it before her coming or think it's ambiguous and you aren't sure? Btw I really appreciate your answer. Thank you so much.

@user203412, it's ambiguous. Joe had done it tells us that (1) the action was in the past, and (2) the action was prior to some other event. But what other event? Without a context we don't know if it was prior to her arrival or prior to Tom speaking. Compare that with "Tom said that Joe did it before she arrived." Now we have a simple past tense but the preposition before is the word that tells us the order of events. There's more than one way to make your meaning clear.
